# How to estimate the proper height of a UITextField, to hold text of given font size

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uikit

I want to display a single-line text field using UITextField and I need to know before displaying it, the proper size for its containing UICollectionViewCell. The text can be one of multiple font sizes and I need to get the right height for displaying it comfortably.

Since the text is not known in advance (it can be edited by the user), I can't use `NSAttributedString`'s `-size` and `-boundingRectWithSize:options:context:` with anything but dummy text, in which case I can't really trust the resulting size to hold any piece of text, right?

I guess my question is: Is there a rule of thumb about typography in general, or some useful API I'm not aware of, that would allow me to determine that for displaying text at `X` pt, I need a text field with a height of `Y` px.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UITextField` implements the `sizeThatFits:` method.  So the most reliable way to get the size of your text field is to actually create one, set it up like you would set up your real text fields, and ask it for a suitable size.  You don't even have to give it placeholder text, because `UITextField` will choose the size based on its font, not on its text.

```
UITextField *dummy = [[UITextField alloc] init];
dummy.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
dummy.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
CGFloat requiredHeight = [dummy sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(HUGE_VALF, HUGE_VALF)].height;
// requiredHeight == 30 in my test
```

If your deployment target is iOS 6.0 or later, you can instead use the `intrinsicContentSize` property, like this:

```
CGFloat requiredHeight = dummy.intrinsicContentSize.height;
// requiredHeight == 30 in my test
```

Note that `sizeThatFits:` still works in iOS 6, but `intrinsicContentSize` is a little easier to understand.

Comment: A third alternative is `NSString`'s `sizeWithFont:` extension method.  The `sizeThatFits:` approach, in my experience, has been more useful for multi-line text.

Comment: @borrrden `sizeWithFont:` won't account for the text field's border, if matehat is using a bordered style.

Comment: I was just experimenting with other things and (just discovered) `[[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20] lineHeight]` also yields 24. I'm wondering if they all take their value from there.

Comment: But you're right that `sizeThatFits` and `intrinsicContentSize` will take things like borders into account

Comment: I just changed my example to use a border style, which changes the result.

Comment: @robmayoff I've been looking at a similar issue and finding that intrinsicContentSize.height never changes from 30 when I change the font size, any clues?

Comment: Same for me - width changes as expected/shown when font changes, but height is always 30 (wether using sizeThatFits or intrinsicContentSize).

Answer (score 4):

iOS always returns a height of 30 units when the borderStyle is RoundedRect.  If you want to compute the height required by a custom font, you have to change the borderStyle to any other value, compute the height, and change the borderStyle back.

```
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
let sizeThatFits = textField.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width:textField.bounds.width, height: CGFloat.max));
textField.bounds.height = sizeThatFits.height;
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect;
```

Comment: this was very helpful. do you have sources for "iOS always returns a height of 30 units when the borderStyle is RoundedRect. " ?